# EEPROM in Simulator for Microchip Pic18f

Tags: pic, microchip, eeprom, xc8

When programming a Microcontroller from Microchip using Pic18F and using XC8 Compiler, can i use Simulator to test / verify it ?

```
eeprom_write(0, 1);
unsigned char value = eeprom_read (0);
```

always returns 0

Note : I Am Starting at Address 0, is the starting address correct ?

Regards

Comment: What happens when you try other addresses?

Comment: nops nothing gets read , using http://microchip.wikidot.com/faq:36

Comment: see: https://www.microchip.com/forums/m952592.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Under MPLABX you could check the EEPROM with the simulator.
Have a look:

> Windows / Target Memory Views / EE Data Memory